# Notice against Vandalism

Tags: feature-request, editing

We should have a notice about vandalism in edits, such as adding notes to answers that have nothing to do with the actual question or the answer itself.

**Example:**

> Answer to a question about sparkleshare.
>
> Editor tries to add "I used it but it was too slow".

There should be a notice explicitly warning them before they try to suggest the edit, if there is not one already (I no longer have to wait for my edits to be accepted so I don't remember if there is such a thing).

Comment: Has this been a frequent problem? Don't people know better, by the time they can edit posts without their edits having to be approved by others?

Comment: @EliahKagan it's frequent enough to make me note it.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. :-( Well, I don't see any disadvantage to adding a short note reminding people that editing questions/answers is not a place to add random information about their experiences/opinions. +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a notice in the sidebar:

> How to Edit
>
> - fix grammatical or spelling errors
> - clarify meaning without changing it
> - correct minor mistakes
> - add related resources or links
> - always respect the original author

You can see it by browsing the site without being logged in, or on another Stack Exchange site where you don't have the edit privilege.

The notice could be more in-your-face, but no matter what it says and how obnoxious it is, it's well-known that users don't read.

Don't be afraid to use that `Reject` button. (I reject about 1 suggested edit in 4 on Stack Overflow.)

Comment: I reject lol, I do think though that a red bar warning may be more likely to deter offenders, as well as a captcha for first timers.